# Auth0 Custom Database and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, auth0

I have used my own database as my Identity provider using auth0 to authenticate users. I have a user table that contains "user_id" as a primary key and also has email and password. How do I set up my database so I can add more user data to my database, creating new tables and all be linked to that user_id?

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Do you want to create a new table or create more fields in your existing table?

Comment: Create a new table.

Comment: You can you mysql workbench or use cli to create a new table. Then if you want to "bound" data in your tables you can use Foreign Keys.

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench. I'll definitely try foreign keys.

Comment: Am I able to use the same foreign key(user_id) in multiple tables?

Comment: FK is a reference to another table with the same values. It means that if you have a user_id in table called Users (for example) and in table called Orders as well and then you can add FK to point from Orders.user_id to Users.user_id.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html (do not forget to select right version of MySQL server).